# Is there a way to place the Tabs to left of the figure in TabView?

Tags: interface, user-interface

I have a very large `LayeredGraphPlot` that is oriented left to right and I have TabView that highlight the paths. But the problem is I have to press Tabs on the top then scroll down to see what is the new path. Is there an option or some hack to get the Tabs in `TabView` not to appear on the top of the figure but on the left?

Comment: Have you seen `ControlPlacement`?

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon stupid me didn't see the `ControlPlacement` ;) thank you!

Comment: Apparently when I publish the notebook to the cloud, the control placement is reset to Top. Too bad `TabView`'s control placement is not supported in the cloud.

Comment: That sounds like something you should tell Support.